# Change tick labels on x-axis ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

In ggplot2 I have created a line graph and have it looking how I want it. However, I am having difficulties changing the values on the x-axis. How can I change the x-axis tick labels from the numbers 1-10 to some text?

Here is my code:

```
pd <- position_dodge(0.1) 

myplot <- ggplot(LL_young_gg, aes(x=Day, y=Mean, colour=Group)) + 
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Mean-SEM, ymax=Mean+SEM), width=.1, position=pd) +
      geom_line(position=pd) + scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "pink", "dark blue", " light blue")) +
      geom_point(position=pd)

myplot + theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank())
```

The database (LL_young_gg) is imported from excel and the column (Day) is numeric 1 through to 10.

Comment: What did you try and what difficulties are you having? Errors? Warnings? Something else? Try looking at the help pages `?scale_x_continuous` (if your x-axis is continuous) or `?scale_x_discrete` (if your x-axis is discrete)

Comment: I've tried the following:-

low10_c_x <- low10_c + scale_x_discrete("Session", labels = c("1"= "D1 on", "2"="D2 off", "3"="D2 on", "4"="D3 off", "5"="D3 on", "6"="D4 off", "7"="D4 on", "8"="D5 off", "9"= "D5 on", "10"="24 FU"))

And it returns the error:

Scale for 'x' is already present. Adding another scale for 'x', which
will replace the existing scale.

Comment: That's not an error, it's a warning. The could should still work. And you can avoid the warning if you don't give it a scale previously. If you show your code and your data we can help. Without those, it is difficult to help more than we have.

Comment: Here is the code for my graph. Adding the code above removes x-axis.

low10_c <- ggplot(LL_young_gg, aes(x=Day, y=Mean, colour=Group)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Mean-SEM, ymax=Mean+SEM), width=.1, position=pd) +
  geom_line(position=pd) + scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "pink", "dark blue", " light blue")) +
  geom_point(position=pd)

low10_c + theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank())

Comment: (a) That's hard to read in the comment without formatting. Please edit the graph coe into your question. (b) What class is the column you put on the x-axis, `Day`? Is it a `Date`? A numeric? Something else? Depending on the answer you may need `scale_x_date` or `scale_x_continuous` or something else. Please show a sample of your data as well as your code. Edit this information into your question please.

Comment: Hi Gregor, I have edited my original question to include code and a description of the data.

Comment: Great, looks like Graeme's answer should work just fine. Use `scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:10, labels = paste0("D", 1:10))`. If you need more help, please share your data reproducibly. `dput(your_data)` is a great way to put your data in a question so  it is copy/pasteable.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `scale_x_continuous()`. A reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)

data(mtcars)

xLabels <- paste(c(4,6,8), "Cylinders")

ggplot(mtcars,
       aes(x = cyl,
           y = qsec
           )
       ) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(4,6,8),
                     labels = xLabels
                     )
```

[image]